# Edit and How to Ask shortcuts?

Tags: support

I remember reading about shortcuts for Edit (the original post) and for How To Ask.  How do include those in my comments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a few auto-linking shortcuts you can use. [Here is the complete list](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting); the ones I use most often are:

- `[edit]` for a link to edit the post. Note that it links to editing the post to which the comment is attached, so if you comment on an answer, the link is to edit that answer and not the parent post.
- `[tour]` goes to the tour in the Help Center.
- `[ask]` goes to How to Ask.
- `[answer]` goes to How to Answer.

Comment: Also, I find `[so]` handy from time to time, for those questions that should be on the main network.